# How to fix ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion

Tags: oracle, plsql, substr, clob

In my pl/sql code i have one parameter 'Error' which is used to display the missing values in table.

```
Error:= '<b><font color="black">following values are missing:</font></b>' 
|| val1||val2||val3||val4;
```

Here ErrorText is `CLOB` datatype and each `val1,val2,val3,val4` are set to `varchar2(2000)`.

So, I guess when it is unable to display val_results more than the CLOB limit of 'Error', its throwing

> ORA-22835.

How can I display 'Error' text only upto CLOB limit?

Comment: It's not the CLOB's limit that's exceeding as you can store upto upto `128 TB` in it. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/limits001.htm . When you say *"unable to display val_results"* , do you mean dbms_output is giving you error?

Answer (score -1):

You have ORA-22835, so it means that it is for conversion **from CLOB to CHAR**. It looks that the exception is thrown in a different place than you think.